# Couldn't upload files to Sharepoint site while passing through Squid Proxy

Tags: sharepoint, squid, ntlm, upload, integrated-authentication

we have this issue: one of our employees is collaborating with a supplier and he needs to upload documents on a Sharepoint site hosted on the supplier's main site. In our environment we use Squid Proxy to allow people navigate on the net (we have NTLM authentication and users transparently authenticate while using IE and FF).

It seems that this specific Sharepoint site is using Integrated Windows Authentication only, and according to some research on the net it seems that this can have troubles with proxies.

More specifically, we have tried two Squid versions:

- with Squid 3.0 we are unable to login to the site (the browser loads an empty page)
- with Squid 2.7 (that supports "[Connection Pinning](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ConnPin)") we are able to login into the site, move on the different sections BUT..

when we try to upload a file that is bigger than a couple of KiloBytes (i.e. 10KB) the browser loads an error page (i think it's a 401 unauthorized but i must verify it)

we've tried changing a couple of Squid options (in 2.7), what we got is that when you try to upload the file you got an authentication box (just like the initial login) and it refuses to go on even if you enter the same authentication credentials.

What's really strange is that when you try to upload a small file (i.e. a text or binary 1KB file) the upload succeeds.

I initially thought that maybe there was something misconfigured on their Sharepoint site but I've tried also this site: www.xsolive.com (it's a sharepoint 2007 demo site) and I've experienced the same problem.

Has any of you experienced such behaviour? Thanks!

Of course we've suggested to the supplier to activate also Basic+SSL and we're waiting for their reply..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we ran into a similar problem and went with the Basic+SSL solution.